# Laravel Mix Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:20)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I am getting an  error in laravel-mix like this.

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:20)

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| class Mix {
|     /** @type {Mix|null} */
>     static _primary = null;
| 
|     /** @type {Record<string, boolean>} */
```

Here is my webpack.mix.js configuration:

```
 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue().sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]);
```

I upgraded node to latest version and upgraded npm to latest version.

```
node  v16.0.0
npm 7.11.2
```

But still I am getting this error.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I am also facing this problem

Comment: My problem solved. In my case, original error comes from vue part.  In vue router index.js file there was 'import { vue } from 'laravel-mix';' that's causes the error. after removing this import statement, error gone. so please check app.js or it's any imported file that's causing this problem.

Comment: Ok thank you. It is same situation. It solved.